# project .msi works only when "Run as Administrator"

Tags: wpf, vb.net

In vb.net+wpf and excel integrated application, I have created setup.msi, then installed application, it works perfectly with "Run as administrator". When I double click .exe and execute, then login prompted twice. Why there is a strange behavior? I dont have any clue of how to fix this.

While executing the code in visual studio, its working well. In my local environment, I have installed the application, its works well when double click on .exe.

But when I set the same in my colleague machine, its prompted with login twice.

In app.manifest file,
`<requestedExecutionLevel level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false" />`
is set.

Application should work without prompting the login screen twice in all machines.

Comment: What installer framework are you using?  wix, nsis?

Comment: have you tried, to add a user to your computer with the same privileges as your collegue and debug it with this new account. maybe you try to acces an object that you need special privilgeges.

Comment: I am using Wix installer framework. @nbk ok I will try your idea.